# Automate hop by hop telnet to Cisco router

Tags: cisco, telnet, netcat

I need to automate telnet to a Cisco router and get a "show version" result. The problem is, I need to first to telnet to A, from there telnet to B and then only be able to telnet to the Cisco router.

I've tried below, but didn't work.

```
root@linux:~#cat command
myName
myPassword
telnet 2.2.2.2
myName2
myPassword2
telnet 3.3.3.3
cisco
ciscoPass
show version

root@linux:~#nc 1.1.1.1 23 -i 1 < command
```

Comment: Everytime I see cisco (or any other manufacturer) and telnet in the tags, I can't help but to think WHY??? S...S...H... why on earth do you want to use a clear text protocol on network devices?

Comment: migration to SSH is in the way. but some of our legacy monitoring and network management software were only setup to use telnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [TCL/Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). It's very handy on this situations. Here follows a sample script (you'll probable have to tweak it a little):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --

if {$argc != 1} {
        puts "Wrong parameters."
        puts "Usage: $argv0 <ip address router 1> <ip address router 2>"

        exit 1
}

# Telnet to router 1
spawn telnet [lindex $argv 0]

expect {
        "Username:"     {send "myuser\r"}
}

expect {
        "assword:" {
                send "mypasswd"
                send "\r"
        }
}

expect "\>"

# Telnet on router 2
# Telnet to router 1
send "telnet [lindex $argv 1]"

expect {
        "Username:"     {send "myuser\r"}
}

expect {
        "assword:" {
                send "mypasswd"
                send "\r"
        }
}

expect "\>"

send "sh ver\r"
expect "\>"

# Quiting router 2
send "quit\r"
expect "\>"

# Quiting router 1
send "quit\r"
expect "Connection closed by foreign host."

wait
exit 0
```

Comment: looks simple enough to use. i'll give it a try first for my case. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
(
  sleep 1
  echo user ; sleep 1
  echo pass ; sleep 1
  echo telnet router2
  sleep 1
  echo user ; sleep 1
  echo pass ; sleep 1
  echo telnet router3
  sleep 1
  echo user ; sleep 1
  echo pass ; sleep 1
  echo sh ver ; sleep 1
) | telnet router1
```

Comment: thanks mario, but i seem to have timing issue. i've tried removing sleep, also sleep 1,2,3 etc with inconsistent success.

Comment: ok - i have tested this script and it works fine in my network. maybe you had to increment the sleep value. try to wait 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Perl library [Net::Telnet::Cisco](http://nettelnetcisco.sourceforge.net) is great to handle this kind of scripts.

You only have to worry about commands and not the telnet communication with the router.

Simple example :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Net::Telnet::Cisco;

if ($#ARGV == -1) {
        print "Usage : $0 <ip address>\n";
}
else {

        my $host = $ARGV[0];
        my $session = Net::Telnet::Cisco->new(Host => $host);

        $session->login('username', 'password');

        my @uptime = $session->cmd('sh ver | i uptime');
        print @uptime;

        $session->close;
}

$ ./uptime_cisco.pl router.mydomain
 router uptime is 3 weeks, 1 day, 16 hours, 55 minutes
```

Netcat is a great tool, but the ease of use of such a library is such that I don't use netcat any more for any automated script.

Comment: hi petrus, this is great script, but i need help to use it to telnet to the second router and run sh ver command at that router.